# Pronunciation of "every body", "every thing" etc. when written as two separate words

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change

How shall I pronounce the words *every body*, *every thing* etc. when meaning *everybody*, *everything*, but **written separately** in the 19th century, like Jane Austen did? **As two words, or as one?**

In the sentence:

> Every body was there

is there an extra stress at the first syllable of the second word, like in

> **Ev**ery **ba**by was there

or is there only one stress at the beginning like in

> **Ev**erybody was there

?

I've sometimes heard Americans pronounced *everybody* as **[ˈɛvrɪˈba:di]** - is it just a local slang, or can it be a relict from the old times where these two parts were perceived as separate words?

Comment: Is there any possible way to pronounce *every body* differently than *everybody* ? I don't think there is any possibility.

Comment: As an American, I find myself pronouncing "everybody" the same as "every buddy", and "every body" as "every" followed by "body". I don't notice much, if any, distinction between "everything" and "every thing". If I notice any difference, it's that I emphasize the "er" in "every" a bit more strongly when saying "every thing" than I do when I say "everything". But I definitely say "everybody" differently than I say "every body". Not sure whether others do as well, will need to listen. "Every body" comes up infrequently in conversation nowadays.

Comment: If it means the same thing as the modern compound word, I think I would pronounce it the same. But if you're saying _Every body in the morgue is on a slab_, referring to all the dead bodies rather than a group of people, I would pronounce it as @Patrick87 describes. In the case of _every thing_, I'd probably have a slight stress change and a tiny pause between the words.

Comment: @BlessedGeek The OP explains it for us. Coumpound nouns such as *everybody* take one stress, usually on the first noun in the compound. Every girl takes two stresses one on each word. Imagine lots of corpses from an accident. You'd probably say 'every 'body was recovered. Not 'everybody was recovered ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Walker's critical pronouncing dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=9OsIAAAAQAAJ&q=body#v=snippet&q=nobody&f=false) from 1824 does not have a pronunciation for *every body*, but gives the pronunciation for *nobody* as /ˈnoʊbɒdi/. That is, the first syllable was accented, but the vowel in the second syllable had not yet been reduced to a schwa.

Since this spelling change almost certainly followed the pronunciation change, I think it's quite safe to assume that *every body* was pronounced the same way: /ˈɛvrɪbɒdi/

Comment: Peter, I can't see it so clearly. Why are you so sure that there is no additional accent on the first syllable of *body*?

Comment: If *nobody* had been treated as two words, the primary accent would be on the *body* and not the *no*. This isn't what Walker says. What I'm assuming is that *everybody* started being treated as one word at the same time as *nobody* did. I can't be sure of this.

Comment: I don't think the fact that some Americans say  /ˈevriˌbɑdi/ means that we treat it like two words. Americans just tend to put more secondary stresses in than Brits. For example, we put secondary stress on the *tar* in *military*, and that was never two words.